# Wha is the Kotlin way to run a function every one second in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, optimization

In my app, I have a realtime chart with the ram usage. So the chart gets updated in one second intervals. Currently I am using couroutines and a while loop with delay functions. But I am curious if this would be the best optimized way to do this. Here's my code.

```
    val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, ex ->
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
    val memoryInfo = MemoryInfo(requireContext())
    lifecycleScope.launch(exceptionHandler + Dispatchers.IO) {
        while (true) {
            memoryInfo.ram()
            usedRam = memoryInfo.usedRam.toFloat()
            Init.usedRam = memoryInfo.usedRam

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                arcProgressRam.progress = memoryInfo.usedRamPercentage.toInt()
                txtUsedRam.text = memoryInfo.usedRam.toInt().toString()
                txtFreeRam.text = memoryInfo.availableRam.toInt().toString()
            }

            val lineData: LineData? = lineChartRam.data
            var iLineDataSet = lineData?.getDataSetByIndex(0)
            if (iLineDataSet == null) {
                iLineDataSet = createSet()
                lineData?.addDataSet(iLineDataSet)
            }

            lineData?.addEntry(Entry(iLineDataSet.entryCount.toFloat(), usedRam), 0)
            lineData?.notifyDataChanged()
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                lineChartRam.notifyDataSetChanged()
                lineChartRam.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(20f)
                lineChartRam.moveViewToX(lineData?.entryCount?.toFloat() ?: 0f)
            }
            delay(1000)
        }
    }
```

So. My question is, Is this would be the best way to do this? does this affect any performance? How to do this with clean code. Also I am new to coroutines and have I used the WithContext option correctly?

Comment: A coroutine is perfectly fine for this. But I think it would make slightly more sense in this case to use Dispatchers.Default for your calculations instead of IO, since you're not doing IO work. Just for semantic reasons...this app isn't juggling lots of parallel work so it won't effectively make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Handler with post delay to repeat the task you want

```
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper

class DelayHandler {
    var handler: Handler? = null
    var runnable: Runnable? = null

    init {
        handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    }

    fun startDelay(sec: Long, listener: () -> Unit) {
        runnable = Runnable { listener.invoke() }
        runnable?.let { handler?.postDelayed(it, sec) }
    }

    fun startLoop(sec: Long, listener: () -> Unit) {
        runnable = Runnable {
            listener.invoke()
            runnable?.let { handler?.postDelayed(it, sec) }
        }
        runnable?.let { handler?.postDelayed(it, sec) }
    }

    fun cancelHandler() {
        if (handler != null) {
            runnable?.let { handler?.removeCallbacks(it) }
        }
    }
}
```

And then Use this class as follows

```
private val delayHandler = DelayHandler()
delayHandler.startLoop(1000) {
// Write your task here

}
```